# Remove entry from array

Tags: arrays, shell, zsh

I want to do sth. like this:

```
foo=(a b c)
foo-=b
echo $foo # should output "a c"
```

How can I remove an entry from an array? `foo-=b` does not work.

The removal should work no matter where the entry is.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To remove element number `$i`: `a=("${(@)a[1,$i-1]}" "${(@)a[$i+1,$#a]}")`

(The simpler construct `a=($a[1,$i-1] $a[$i+1,-1])` also removes empty elements.)

**ADDED:**

To remove any occurence of `b`: `a=("${(@)a:#b}")`
`:#` is the hieroglyph to remove matching elements; `""` and `(@)` is to operate correctly on arrays even if they contain empty elements.

Comment: This looks quite complicated. Also, how do I get `$i`? I just want to remove `b`.

Comment: @Albert: I've added how to remove by content.

Comment: Thanks, that addition is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: See my answer for a much simpler solution.

Comment: shouldn't `a=("${(@)a[1,`... be `a=("${(@)a[0,` (starting at 0), since arrays are 0-based indexed?

Comment: @Blauhirn Zsh's arrays are 1-based by default (they can be 0-based but you have to activate ksh compatibility mode).

Comment: `#a` is the index of the last elem of a? So `:#` should remove the last elem, but no...

Comment: @Timo One does not follow from the other. `${a:#}` is parsed as the `${VARIABLE:#PATTERN}` parameter expansion construct, not as the `${VARIABLE:INDEX}` construct. Furthermore `${a:$#a}` wouldn't remove the last element, it would take a slice starting after the last element, so it would be an empty array.

Comment: FWIW, you can use -1 instead of $#a as the end index.

Answer (score 43):

Gilles second answer is correct if you wish to remove all occurences, but it is a full reassignment of the array and does not address the situation where you wish to remove only a single entry, regardless of duplicates. There is a way in zsh to remove an element from an normal array without reassigning the entire array:

Given the following array:

```
array=(abc def ghi)
```

the following will return the index of the first match for `def`:

```
${array[(i)def]}
```

and the following format can be used to remove any given indexed value (element index 2 in this example) in an array without reassignment of the entire array:

```
array[2]=()
```

thus, to remove the value `def` we combine the two:

```
array[$array[(i)def]]=()
```

This is cleaner for single element removal, since there is no explicit array reassignment (cleaner in that any potential side effects, such as the accidental removal of empty items, quoted format issues, etc. are not going to crop up). However Gilles' solution is largely equivalent and has the advantage of multiple matching item removal, if that is what you want. With his method and this method, you have a full toolset for standard array element removal.

Comment: Also relevant: use `(I)` to remove the last match instead of the first one. Add `e` to the `i`/`I` flag to get an exact match; `zsh` usually does pattern matching here, ie `def*` would remove the first element that begins with `def`.

Comment: for more about reassigning/removing array slices, see [the Zsh Guide, section 5.4.1 - "Parameter substitution: Using arrays"](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html#l121)

Comment: This one worked for me to remove an item from the plugins list in zsh 5.9 - Jérôme's answer resulted in an error where oh-my-zsh seemed to be reading the plugins array as a single string.

Answer (score 20):

Since versions [4.2 and 5.0](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html), zsh accepts `${name:|arrayname}` syntax. [From manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

> If `arrayname` is the name (N.B., not contents) of an array variable, then any elements contained in `arrayname` are removed from the substitution of `name`.

So, it does exactly what you expect:

```
$ foo=(a b c)
$ excl=(b)
$ echo ${foo:|excl}
a c
```

Answer (score 7):

`foo = (1 2 3)`

`shift foo`

`print $foo`
gives: 2 3

So this removes the first element (is that what you want?)

[edited]

remove the ith element with

`foo[$i] =()`

instead.

Comment: No, I want to remove the entry whereever it is (it is not always at the beginning).

Comment: What is `$i`? How do I get it?

Comment: @Dennis: You mean `$i=b`? That doesn't work. `foo(b)=()` is not valid.

Comment: @Albert: No I mean `i=2`, which is what the last option in this answer is intended to do. However, it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To remove element with content "b" from array:

```
foo=(a b c)
foo=(${foo#b})
```

Comment: This will transform `(foo bar foobar)` into `(bar bar)`!

Comment: No, it doesn't: `foo=(foo bar foobar) ; foo=(${foo#bar}) ; echo $foo` returns `foo foobar`.

Comment: Incorrect: `foo=(a ab ac ad) ; foo=(${foo#a}) ; declare foo` gives `foo=(b c d)` (expected `foo=(ab ac ad)`).

Comment: @TheDoctorWhat He's saying `foo#foo` not `foo#bar`.

Comment: To clarify, `foo=(foo bar foobar barfoo);foo=(${foo#bar});declare foo` returns `foo=( foo foobar foo )`.