# How can I remove a path from $PATH in Zsh and add it to the beginning without duplication?

Tags: zsh

I have:

```
PATH=/bar:/foo
```

I want:

```
PATH=/foo:/bar
```

I don't want:

```
PATH=/foo:/bar:foo
```

So I'm thinking, given the default path is `PATH=/bar`, I can modify `$path` (which is `$PATH` as an associative array):

```
function prepend_to_path() {
  unset $path[(r)$1]
  path=($1 $path)
}

prepend_to_path /foo
```

But that complains with:

```
prepend_to_path:unset:1: not enough arguments
```

It's been so long that I don't even remember what `(r)` is for, but without it (`unset $path[$1]`) I get:

```
prepend_to_path:1: bad math expression: operand expected at `/home/nerd...'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the body of your function with:

```
path=($1 ${(@)path:#$1})
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435429/1107999

Answer (score 2):

This also works (and is arguably easier to read when you go back to it after a couple of months):

```
prepend_to_path () {
  path[1,0]=$1 
  typeset -U path
}
```

`typeset -U` will automatically deduplicate the array, keeping only the first occurrence of each element.

Since `export` is equivalent to `typeset -gx`, you could also `export -U path` to kill two birds with one stone.

**Edit:**  `typeset -U` needs only to be applied to a particular array once, so one can do that somewhere in one's shell startup and remove the line from the function above.